# Python how to make string from file to dictionary in list

Tags: python-3.x

I have file with format string like below. With always six field and sometime user wrong typing for some field so I try to use regex to match the field.

```
name : Luke Skywalker
hp. : 0813412345678
address : Jl. Gagak 3 No.5 Bandung Selatan
product : TSirt Starwars 
quantity : 1
note : size L

name : Qui-Gon Jinn
hp. : 08156898234567
address : Jl. Tatoon No.142 Bandung Barat
product : pants Chino Krem
quantity : 1
note : size L

name : Obi-Wan Kenobi
hp. : 08877763212312
address : Jl. Pemuda No.66 Bandung Selatan
product : TSirt Starwars 
quantity : 1
note : size L
```

And I want make dictionary in the list with format like this.

```
[
    {
        'name': 'Luke Skywalker', 
        'mobile': '0813412345678', 
        'address': 'Jl. Gagak 3 No.5 Bandung Selatan', 
        'product': 'TSirt Starwars', 
        'quantity': '1', 
        'note': 'size L'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Qui-Gon Jinn', 
        'mobile': '08156898234567', 
        'address': 'Jl. Tatoon No.142 Bandung Barat', 
        'product': 'pants Chino Krem', 
        'quantity': '1', 
        'note': 'size L'
    }, 
    {
        'name': 'Obi-Wan Kenobi', 
        'mobile': '08877763212312', 
        'address': 'Jl. Pemuda No.66 Bandung Selatan', 
        'product': 'TSirt Starwars', 
        'quantity': '1', 
        'note': 'size L'
    }
]
```

So far I have been success with this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re


_lst = []

with open("filetoread.txt", "r") as read_file:
    _tmp_name = []
    _tmp_mobile = []
    _tmp_alamat = []
    _tmp_produk = []
    _tmp_jml = []
    _tmp_note = []

    for i in read_file:
        if i is not "\n":
            _splt = i.split(":")
            if re.compile(r"nam[a|e]", re.I).match(_splt[0].strip()):
                _tmp_name.append({"name":_splt[1].strip()})

            if re.compile(r"^hp(\.\s)?|^hand\w|telp(\.\s)?", re.I).match(_splt[0].strip()):
                _tmp_mobile.append({"mobile":_splt[1].strip()})

            if re.compile(r"alamat|address", re.I).match(_splt[0].strip()):
                _tmp_alamat.append({"addredd":_splt[1].strip()})

            if re.compile(r"produk|item", re.I).match(_splt[0].strip()):
                _tmp_produk.append({"product":_splt[1].strip()})

            if re.compile(r"jml(\.\s)?|jumlah|total", re.I).match(_splt[0].strip()):
                _tmp_jml.append({"quantity":_splt[1].strip()})

            if re.compile(r"note", re.I).match(_splt[0].strip()):
                _tmp_note.append({"note":_splt[1].strip()})

    _zip = list(zip(_tmp_name, _tmp_mobile, _tmp_alamat, _tmp_produk, _tmp_jml, _tmp_note))

    l = []
    for z in _zip:
        d = {}
        for i in z:
            d.update(i)
        l.append(d)


    print(l)
```

But I'm not really sure with this code. Is there a better way to do it in the python way which is simpler and clever.

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have a simple solution for your problem but you need to change names after dictionary make

```
result = list()
tmp_obj = dict()
for line in open('input.txt', 'r').readlines():

    if len(line) > 1:
        key, value = line.split(':')
        tmp_obj[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    else:
        result.append(tmp_obj)
        tmp_obj = dict()
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you Ali, I will try your solution.

Comment: The problem with your code is, if my user typo or don't give empty line for their data. Because frequency user wrong typing is high.

Comment: ah you dont mention it. so what is our fixed field? we have all those fields after each other and always?

Comment: Ya sorry I will fix the question, I just have six field and always six but sometimes user wrong typing for some field and they don't give empty space for each data like I do in sample. So I use regex in my code. Thanks